# Is it possible randomize data that has been serialized using System.Serializable

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

A made a quiz game using Serializable method. As I call data from there it is always in same sequence. What I want to do is serialize questions and answers. And later I want to call data in random order.

Sorry about my previous question. Actually I'm new here that is why made the mistake. Really SORRY

Thank you guys :)

I am giving a link to the training session in case you need anything not specified here (all codes of the Project given there)
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/intro-and-setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to be more specific in what you are asking.
You have both 2d and 3d tags for unity up pick the one you are using.

If you are working in one persistent scene, that means you will have to manipulate everything manually to remove it or reset it.

Another option is that you save the data you need from that round in a don't destroy on load object and reload your scene.

I would suggest you make 2 scenes, a menu scene, and a play-scene.

Read up on scenemanager and place a button in the menu scene that lets you move to the play-scene.

make a game object that holds information you want keep from every round.
for example; this object will hold the coins when you leave the scene.

```
 public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour
 {
   public int coins;
   public static GameControl gamecontrol;
   void Awake()
  {
    if (gamecontrol == null)
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        gamecontrol = this;

    }
      else if (gamecontrol != this)
     {
        Destroy(gameObject);
     }
   }
}
```

After you added the coins to this object at the end of the round.
Leave the scene at end of round and go to the menu scene.
Now you can open new round in menu and you can keep the coins.

Comment: JEREON I have edited my question so that it make sense. Please give me a solution

Comment: u should try to show some code and where you are stuck at and try new ideas. i would start by making a list<questions> and  transfer it into new list after deserializing it, as u do that use random positions to insert each question.

Comment: I am giving all codes and let me how I can deserialize it and use random positions using c# script